show document name in cups macos history
Bothering this for a long time; how can I show the printed document name in the cups history? When i look at the history in cups ( http://localhost:631/jobs?which_jobs=all ) I see only
 Brother_MFC_J6520DW-75 | Unknown | Withheld | 201k | 1 | completed at Mon
 Nov 25 19:36:40 2024

What do I need to do anywhere to get the document name to appear in the printers log?
So far as I can see there is no application that shows or send the documents name to the printer. Is there a kind of hidden privacy button?
I got several printers but none of them shows the document name; but in case someone need it, this is my lpoptions output.

copies=1
device-uri=dnssd://Brother%20MFC-J6520DW._ipp._tcp.local./?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c6dd0ca
finishings=3 job-cancel-after=10800 job-hold-until=no-hold
job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=1732607566
marker-high-levels=100,100,100,100 marker-levels=19,12,29,1
marker-low-levels=17,17,17,18
marker-types=inkCartridge,inkCartridge,inkCartridge,inkCartridge
number-up=1 printer-commands=none printer-info='Brother MFC-J6520DW'
printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=false
printer-is-temporary=false printer-location='Instanbul Turkije'
printer-make-and-model='Brother MFC-J6520DW-AirPrint' printer-state=3
printer-state-change-time=1732607636
printer-state-reasons=marker-supply-low-warning printer-type=2142300
printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost/printers/Brother_MFC_J6520DW

Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

show document name in cups macos history? What do I need to do anywhere to get the document name to appear in the printers log? Isn't that clear?
